Need Help Migrating A Drop Down List From One Workbook To Another
I need some help migrating a drop down list and the data selected from that list to another workbook.
I have a list of people that need to be contacted each week, with an updated file that is sent to me weekly. We have a drop down that details how people in my department have contacted the people on the list. Emailed, Called, No Message, Do Not Contact, etc.
My issue is that I cannot figure out how to migrate both the drop down list & the data selected to the new weekly sheet. I can copy the list over by copying & pasting, but when I try to use a VLOOKUP to move the selected data over, it tells me it's not the right data type.
I change both data points to be validated for list data & it still doesn't work, giving me the same error that the data isn't validated correctly. I then tried validating for all data, and that pulls the data over, but it doesn't preserve the list formatting for my coworkers to select new options when they need to.
I can paste with a link and that copies the data & list formatting over, but then I'm not able to associate the data with the correct record since this list is changing in size every week. I'm not sure exactly what to do, so any guidance would be greatly appreciated!

It would be useful to see sample data (before and after copying), the formula & validation you have tried, etc...

Please post a section of your Excel input file. Please, don't post a screenshot use this VBA code or use this website to create a Markdown table and edit it into your question.

The Help Center reference for Markdown
